# Add App Link when posting video on behalf of user to Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, video

I am currently posting a video to Facebook's graph API on iOS behalf of the user.  Everything works properly.  User is able to sign in through facebook, accept that the app is publishing to their timeline on their behalf, and successfully publishes.  I want to add an App Link that was I generated using Facebook's Mobile Hosting API.  But I'm not sure where I can add this parameter.  From my research, it looks like this is only possible through the OpenGraphAPI?  Here is a snippet of my API call:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph-video.facebook.com/\    (userID)/videos?access_token=\(accessToken)")!

    let params = [
        "title": "",
        "description": message
    ]

    var uploadRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST, URL: url, parameters: params)
    uploadRequest.addMultipartData(videoData, withName: "source", type: "multipart/form-data", filename: pathURL.absoluteString)

    uploadRequest.performRequestWithHandler({ (responseData, urlResponse, error) -> Void in
```

....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you submit your app for App Center, the video posts will automatically show a small app-attribution link. That will direct to App Center, from which people can download your app. As you can see in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/), there is no explicit parameter for an App Link.

Comment: Does submitting to the App Center also solve this problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342837/posted-video-on-behalf-of-user-on-timeline-but-facebook-timeline-not-redirectin

Thanks for the reply Roemer!

Comment: Probably. There are currently some known issues with the app attribution links; even if you are not listed in the App Center the post still tries to link to it.